# Upgrading spring-security to 5.7.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I had this issue with upgrading spring-boot to 2.7.5, spring-cloud train to 2021.0.5 and sprint-security to 5.7.5 where as much as I tried sprint-security ended up in version 5.7.4. I finally found out that the cause of that was 5.7.4 being a managed version and I get around that making 5.7.5 my own managed version. However, I do have this question:

Why is 5.7.4 the managed version in boot-2.7.5 and not 5.7.5? Is it a question of simply spring didn't updated their own pom's yet or is there any issue with spring-security 5.7.5 itself that somehow is not recommended to use with boot-2.7.5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because at the time 2.7.5 was released Spring Security 5.7.5 wasn't released yet. Just add `<spring.security.version>5.7.5</spring.security.version>` to the properties to override the version.